# Called php system function to pass in vars

Tags: php

I used php system function to call a file that uses PHPWord to create word docs.

In my code there is:

```
system("php /MissionAgreement.php $var1, $var2 etc.. etc..
```

In the file `MissionAgreement.php` I tried doing

`echo $var1` it tells me undefined variable.

when I use the system function to pass in vars am I supposed to use 
anything special to use the `$var` in the passed file `MissionAgreement.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `MissionAgreement.php`, you need to use [$argc](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php) and [$argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) to get the command line arguments that your system call is passing to it, and then assign those values  to `$var1`, `$var2`, etc.

Or alternatively, you can use [getopt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php)

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will try it out and it makes sense. It should have rang a bell. Variables or command line argument passed in the command line isn't a GET, POST or REQUEST; that was my misunderstand since it isn't related to http protocol. I looked at $argc and $argv, in addition to getopt() function which makes sense in using system() to pass in args to retrieve them in the script that its triggering.